# can't get mongoid/rails field to accept input as array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm creating a Question/Answer model in a Mongoid/Rails project. I want users to create their own questions and then create possible answers: 2 answers or 3 answers or more. I've got the form so they can add as many questions as they want, but I get this error:

```
Field was defined as a(n) Array, but received a String with the value "d".
```

Not only am I not getting the array, but it's wiping out "a" "b" and "c" answers and only saving "d".

My model:

```
class Question
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :question
  field :answer, :type => Array
end
```

The relevant section of _form.html.haml:

```
.field
  = f.label :question
  = f.text_field :question
%p Click the plus sign to add answers.
.field
  = f.label :answer
  = f.text_field :answer
#plusanswer
  = image_tag("plusWhite.png", :alt => "plus sign")

.actions
  = f.submit 'Save'
```

The jQuery that repeats the answer field when they need it:

```
$("#plusanswer").prev().clone().insertBefore("#plusanswer");
```

I've tried several of the solutions here involving [] in the field but getting nowhere.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

One is to edit the form such that instead of returning back question[answer], it returns question[answer][] which will build answer to be an array.

*EDIT: I'm reading your question closer and it seems like you have some JS dynamically rendering forms.  In that case, setting the id with an empty bracket set [] at the end should turn the form object returned into an array*

The other is to override the setter in the model to convert a string into an array.  The safest way is to create a matching getter

```
class Question
  field :answer, type: Array

  def answer_as_string
    answer.join(',')
  end

  def answer_as_string=(string)
    update_attributes(answer: string.split(','))
  end
end
```

Then use `:answer_as_string` in your form

Comment: Thanks Ron. Your second approach didn't give a different result, and I don't understand your first suggestion well enough to try it. I don't know how or where to set the id with an empty bracket set.

Comment: I think I figured it out!
`= f.text_field :answer, :name => "question[answer][]"`
That's still not exactly what I want because my show page displays my separate answers as ["x", "y", "z"] when I want them to show on 3 separate lines with labels, but I'm thinking my next step is to run a jQuery loop to show them that way.

Comment: Uh-oh. Not quite. Now when I edit a question it shows up with the question in it's field, but the answers show up in one field and as the array: ["x", "y", "z"], instead of 3 separate fields. Makes sense I guess, but if I edit it and save, then backslashes get added in front of the double quotes. Edit again and backslashes in front of backslashes. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do a lot wrangling back and forth of the values between javascript and your model and you understand how to use fields_for and nested attributes a better approach might be to make answers separate model and embed them in the question model as so:

```
class Question
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :answers
end

class Answer
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :content # or whatever you want to name it
end
```

Your form would look like this (pardon my HAML):

```
.field
  = f.label :question
  = f.text_field :question
%p Click the plus sign to add answers.
= f.fields_for :answers do |ff|
  .field
    = ff.label :content
    = f.text_field :content
  #plusanswer
    = image_tag("plusWhite.png", :alt => "plus sign")

.actions
  = f.submit 'Save'
```